# Getting teamcity to run unit tests using typemock

Tags: unit-testing, msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity, typemock

i am new to TeamCity and i am trying to configure it to build and run all the unit test in the solution. it is working fine for the test which are not using TypeMock but its failing for those which is using TypeMock.

i have gone through a lot of posts on typemock.org and stackoverflow too but i didnt get any clear step by step solution to fix this.

What i did yet is

added the list of assemblies which i am using

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\MsTest.exe
C:\TeamCity\AutoDeploy\TypeMock.dll
C:\TeamCity\AutoDeploy\TypeMock.MSBuild.dll
C:\BuildAgent\work\d0c2681a8633b717\www.Domain.Tests\bin\Release\qqq.Domain.Tests.dll
```

i am missing some build configuration but i am not sure if i have to do it for MSTest too

Comment: What actually is the problem? Are you getting an error message? Or does TeamCity simply not "see" the tests?

Comment: team city is saying TypeMock is not enabled

Comment: Please tell us the *exact* message.

Comment: TypeMock.TypeMockException: 
*** Typemock Isolator is currently disabled. Enable using the following:

 * Within Visual Studio: 
   - Use Typemock Smart Runner  
   - For other runners, Choose Typemock Menu and click Resume Mocking
 
 * To run Typemock Isolator as part of an automated process you can:
    - run tests via TMockRunner.exe command line tool
    - use 'TypeMockStart' tasks for MSBuild or NAnt
 
For more information consult the documentation (see 'Running Unit Tests in an Automated Build')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer I work at Typemock.

The best solution in your case is to use some kind of a build script like MSBuild or nant
If you are not using a build script you can set the TeamCity process to run with Isolator enabled. Here are the steps to do this:

- In TeamCity projects page go to project you wish to change and hit Settings.
- In the settings page go to the build parameters and choose edit.
- In edit page choose add new parameter.
- In the edit box in the Type section select Environment variable (env.)
- In the Name text box put Cor_Enable_Profiling
- In the value text box put 0x1
- Hit the Save button

Repeat the steps above one more time but change the name of the environment variable to COR_PROFILER and the value to {B146457E-9AED-4624-B1E5-968D274416EC}

This will cause the TeamCity and its child processes (like msbuild) to run profiled with Isolator.
Again, I don't think this is the best solution but it should do the job for you.

Comment: Why is this not recommended?

Comment: It's been a while since I gave the answer and I no longer works at Typemock so things might be different now. However the reason was that you can't do things like running with other profilers when you use that method. Also it is too explicit. The clsid might change in future versions and it will break the build.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are gettig this error because, you did not configure TypeMock to run the test using MSTest. This you can do if did not do yet in your TeamCity Build Agent machine by following the below steps:

1. Windows "Start" >> All Programs >> TypeMock Folder >> Isolator Folder >> Open Isolator Configuration
2. In the new windows opened under `Profilers/Code Coverage` tab, check the check box `Show only available profilers` and in the drop down above that it should list NCover (This is with the assumption that you are using NCover for profiling unit test cases coverage and all).
3. Select NCover from drop down and click on `Link with TypeMock Isolator`.

By this TypeMock Isolator will be configured to profile unit test as well and by that I think your TypeMock disabled issue will be resolved I hope.

**EDIT:**

Sorry for the wrong point. The above will help you if you are using profilers like NCover in your build.

You should use the below MSBuild to run test using MSTest and TypeMock:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="RunTests" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <UsingTask TaskName="NCover.MSBuildTasks.NCover" AssemblyFile="C:\Program Files\NCover\Build Task Plugins\NCover.MSBuildTasks.dll" />
    <Import Project ="C:\Program Files (x86)\Typemock\Isolator\6.1\TypeMock.MSBuild.Tasks" />

    <PropertyGroup>
         <MSTest>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"</MSTest>    
    </PropertyGroup>


    <Target Name ="RunTests">
         <TypeMockStart Target="3.5" />
         <Exec ContinueOnError="true"  Command='$(MSTest) /noisolation "/testcontainer:C:\continuousintegration\root\CTM_VPOFFICEClassLibraries\CTM.VPOffice\CTM.VPOffice Unit Testing\bin\Release\CTM.VPOffice Unit Testing.dll"' />
         <TypeMockStop />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

You can ignore the NCover related things in the above sample and the just ignore the Isolator Configuration steps if you don't have Test profiling in your build process.

Comment: i have a doubt, should i create a new project file and add the above code to it or should i append this code to the existin test project file

Comment: You should not append it to your *.csproj file. I suppose you have a different MSBuild project file used by the TeamCity build which in turn use the *.csproj or *.sln file internally to build. In that case, you can add this to that external MSBuild project file. If not, please add one so because I feel it is not good to tamper *.csproj file much for this.